# Using Microsoft Query in an Excel sheet with dynamic file location

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have two tables in the same Excel 2013 workbook and I want to create a new table within the same workbook that performs left outer join between these two tables using Microsoft Query.

I was able to do that just fine, but the problem is that the SQL statement of the query takes the location of the Excel file as a fixed file path, so if I change the file location the query stops working.

Is there a way to give the query a dynamic for location specially that all the tables are in the same file? 
Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this formula.  =cell("filename",a2).  Make sure the file is saved else it will throw an error.